# Bootstrap CSS form class is overiding btn class for submit button styling

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5

I'm using laravel to create a form styled with bootstrap css.

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => '/hold', 'method' => 'POST', 'class' => 'form-horizontal']) !!}

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label($detail->name, NULL, array('class'=>'control-label')) !!}
        {!! Form::text('detail['.$detail->name.']', null, ['class' => 'controls']) !!}
    </div>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    {!! Form::submit('Hold', ['class'=>'btn btn-danger', 'style' => 'float:right;']) !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

[image: creates a disparity in button sizes]

According to Chrome dev tools, the css selector that is overriding the .btn style rules is `button, html input[type="button"], input[type="reset"], input[type="submit"]`

I'm guessing that the `html input` class takes precedence over the `btn` class. I do not know how to prevent this and force `btn` to take precedence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the whole form with a div that has a custom class - call it `.form-container` - and then override the style within the custom container. This is super easy if you are using Sass, not much harder if you are using CSS though.

HTML - just add custom class:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => '/hold', 'method' => 'POST', 'class' => 'form-horizontal form-container']) !!}

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label($detail->name, NULL, array('class'=>'control-label')) !!}
        {!! Form::text('detail['.$detail->name.']', null, ['class' => 'controls']) !!}
    </div>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    {!! Form::submit('Hold', ['class'=>'btn btn-danger', 'style' => 'float:right;']) !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Sass:

```
.form-container {
  input[type="reset"] {
    // style here
  }
}
```

CSS:

```
.form-container input[type="reset"] {
    // style here
}
```

Comment: CSS selector `.form-container button` didn't apply the style to the submit button. The element type is not `button`, it's `input`. I don't want to apply the style rule to all inputs in the form.

Comment: You can target a specific input within the container - I updated the code to show you how. Same pattern I explained in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

try adding .btn-sm in your button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
```

Comment: Yup, you gave the best answer @scaisEdge